# Replace \n by \r when line (comming from a pipe) contains pattern with GNU sed

Tags: sed, replace, pipe, newline, carriage-return

I want to use with GNU sed to replace \n by \r when each line (comming from a pipe) begins with a specified pattern but my sed command does not seem to work :

```
$ cat mpv_all.log | sed -z '/^AV:/s/\n/\r/g'
```

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `-z` causes the whole file to be read in at once.  Consequently, `^AV:` only matches if the file starts with `AV:`.  You probably want to match `AV:` on each line.  In that case, try:

```
sed -Ez ':a; s/((^|[\n\r])AV:[^\n\r]*)\n/\1\r/g ;ta' mpv_all.log
```

How it works:

- `-E` turns on Extended Regular Expressions.
- `:a` defines label `a`.
- `s/((^|[\n\r])AV:[^\n\r]*)\n/\1\r/g` replaced `\n` with `\r` at the end of any line that starts with `AV:`.
- `ta` tells sed to go back to label `a` if the previous substitute command resulted in any changes.  This is necessary because patterns could overlap and the `g` modifier to the `s` command does not do overlaps.

Comment: This regexp seems a little complicated to me. Can the `\n` by replaced without the `-z` option of `sed` ?

Comment: Under normal conditions, sed removes the `\n` before creating the pattern space and then adds a `\n` to the end of the pattern space before printing it.  So, you do need some kind of special handling.  If you have GNU sed, then `-z` is a  good method.

Answer (score 1):

if awk is also an option:

```
awk '{ORS=/^AV:/?"\r":"\n"}1' file
```

`ORS` is **o**utput **r**ecord **s**eparator; which is set to `\n` by default. but in above script, its value is dynamically changed to `\r` or `\n` depending on whether input line matches `/^AV:/` (i.e begins with `AV:`) or not.

`ORS=/^AV:/?"\r":"\n"` is a shorthand for

```
if (/^AV:/)
  ORS="\r"
else
  ORS="\n"
```

the `1` at the end of the script stands for `{print}`.

Comment: I like this one also, but I don't understand it. Can you explain in your answer the meaning of the `?` mark and the `1` at the end of the awk instructions ?

Comment: Just to sum things up (for others like me later) : The `1` at the end of the awk instructions means to print every line. So, it can be replaced by a single `print;` right before the closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a perl implementation :

```
$ perl -p -e '$| = 1;s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;s/Saving state/\nSaving state/;' mpv_all.log
```

- `-p` loops on every line of the file
- `-e` runs the perl command in the quotes
- `$| = 1;` Perl flushes the buffer at every line
- `s/\n/\r/g if $_ =~ /^AV:/;` replace `\n` by `\r` in every line begining with `AV:`
- OPTIONAL : `s/Saving state/\nSaving state/;` puts the `Saving state` line one line below so as not to overwrite the last line contaning `AV:`